# wordpress: A way to execute shortcode when button is clicked

Tags: jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I'm new with wordpress and am having some problems with shortcodes:
I was trying to execute a shortcode (gridfx) when content is loaded and actually when a tab is clicked and the tabbed area is visible (where the shortcode content should go). I achieve it like that:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#docu').click(function() {
        <?php 
        $short = '[gridfx theme="light" posttypes="product" postids="'.$postids .'" include_terms=75,70,72,76,84,223,225,221,219,194,192,193,191 single_show_content=9 show_overlay_title_v2=0 show_overlay_title=0 sortmenu=0 instantsearch=0 columns=3 items_container_width=100 excerpt_below_title=15]'; 
        $sh = do_shortcode($short); ?>
        jQuery('.short').text('<?php echo $sh ?>');

    });

});
```

but the result in firefox on site refresh is like:
jQuery('.short').text('

')}
and the result is being displayed the wrong way (html is broken).
So the shortcode is executing on sideload and not on click event. Is there a way to achieve this? 
The reason I'm asking is that loading content from shortcodes in a non visible area leads to the point that the result of the shortcode is not displayed or displayed only with 1px height. (In my case).  So actually I'm executing the shortcode in a tab-pane, basically when the tabnav is being clicked, it seems that the shortcode is executed on side load and not on tabpane show.
I need some advise please!
Thanks a lot!
jimmi4u

Comment: I think that is not going to work this way… Why? because a shortcode is a php function like, and you can not execute some php function after page has been loaded on an "on click" event without reloading. You need to use **wordpress Ajax** to do it. This is what i think… and may be i am wrong.

Comment: thanks for your comment! yeah I heard about that ;) But can't I define when the shortcode is executed? I think maybe from javascript calling a php function where the shortcode is executed. What do u think?

Comment: Of course you can trigger through jQuery/ajax a `do_shordcode('[my_shortcode]')` embedded in a function called by a PHP Ajax wordpress function. Everything is possible or almost :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.text( ... )` to add the content. But this removes all html. And you might need to add slashes

```
jQuery('.short').html('<?php echo addslashes($sh); ?>');
```

If this does not work, is there an error inside the console?

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your comment! I tried it with html also but the results were simillar. I think that LoicTheAztec is right, but I have to fugure out the callback function of the plugin and that wan't be that easy with all the values.... The slashes are there. Some other thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I'm a step further with the addslashes and am getting the following error: [code]
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 
jQuery('.short').html('
[/code]
seems like the shortcode isn't returning correct html? Should I json_encode? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `<?php echo $sh ?>` to a variable
Try this :

```
var sh = '<?php echo $sh ?>';
$('.short').html(sh);
```